# How to setup cmake library project with export to be consumed by other cmake projects

Tags: cmake

I am having hard time understanding proper usage of CMakes install/export commands. I would like to have a **CMakeLists.txt** that generates a (solution) for a static library that could be consumed by (different, independent) CMake projects by using `find_package` command.

I have a root folder with four files:

- /hello.cpp
- /hello_private.h
- /hello_public.h
- /CMakeLists.txt

Where **CMakeLists.txt** is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)
project (hellolib)

add_library(hellolib hello_public.h hello_private.h hello.cpp)

set_target_properties(hellolib PROPERTIES
  PUBLIC_HEADER "hello_public.h")

export(TARGETS hellolib FILE hellolib-config.cmake)

install(TARGETS hellolib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/public_headers"
  )

install(FILES hello_public.h
    DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/public_headers)
```

This generates the solution for the library, including the INSTALL project that stages the **.lib** and the public headers. It also generates the **hellolib-config.cmake** which is my understanding is what **find_package()** uses.

My other directory (project) has just two files, **world.cpp** and the **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project (helloworldexe)

add_executable(helloworldexe hello.cpp)

set(hellolib_DIR "C:/deleteMe/cmake/out/lib")
find_package(hellolib REQUIRED)

#----- not sure how to do below? -----
#include_directories(${hellolib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (helloworldexe hellolib)
```

The above seems to fire the **find_package** successfully and add the **hellolib.lib** to the executable project. However I am missing a call to add the exported public headers from the lib. Not sure if it's me, by I find CMake documentation to be rather confusing; various online vids and forums discussing "modern cmake" vs "classic cmake" just add to the confusion. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: By using the target_link_libraries command for hellolib you are adding the PUBLIC and INTERFACE header directories to the target as well.